# Yahoo Weather Icon

Tags: javascript, html, icons, weather, yahoo-weather-api

[image: Weather Icon]

Is there away to display just the Yahoo weather icon above on a webpage? I'm using geektool on my Mac and it can be displayed on my desktop but I'm wondering if it is possible to just have that icon in a webapge??? ANy ideas :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617912/yahoo-weather-api-json-icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had anothet good look around and finaly found what I was looking for, this was exactly what I needed;

http://blog.unijimpe.net/reporte-del-clima-en-php/

The website is spanish but figured most of it out wiht google translator ;)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/XX.gif

where XX is your status code returned from the API?

Example: http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/24.gif

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The [response of Yahoo Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#examples) contains an image that denotes the weather.

The path to the current weather image is `channel > item > description > img` (inside CDATA)

View the below responses in Firefox and then you can see those icons for yourself.

1. New York City - http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2459115
2. Paris, France - http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=615702

Comment: Do the icons update live though? The point of it is is that I don't want to embed a yahoo widget but just the icon...