# Yahoo Weather api JSON Icon

Tags: javascript, html, json, yahoo-weather-api

So i would just like to know is it possible using the current Yahoo Weather API to display a better image than what the JSON response sends back within CDATA?

**JSON:**

Using the api i get the JSON response as example [HERE](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#channel).

**Current Image:**

Currently its windy and the image i get from API Json format CDATA looks like this: [IMAGE](http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/23.gif)

**Image i would like to show:**

What i would like is the nice images you can see here on the right side navigation: [Yahoo](https://za.yahoo.com/?p=us)

Is this possible or is the image in json CDATA the only option i can use?

**Current Code(works):**

```js
var queryURL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22anglesey%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

$.getJSON(queryURL, function (data) {
  
  var results = data.query.results
  var firstResult = results.channel.item.condition
  var link = results.channel.image.link
  var img_link_url = results.channel.image.url
  
  var name = results.channel.location.city
  console.log(firstResult);console.log(link);console.log(img_link_url);
    
  var description = results.channel.item.description
  console.log(description);
    


var regex = /img.*?src=("|')(.*?)\1/i;
var match = description.match(regex)[2];
console.log(match);
    
  var location = firstResult.location // not returned in response
  var temp = firstResult.temp
  var text = firstResult.text
  
 var cels =  (temp - 32) * (5 / 9);
// if  text = "party cloudy -> class = pcloudy || if  text = "cloudy -> class = cloudy || sunny, rainy"
// or use code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216140/how-can-i-get-yahoo-weather-backgrounds-from-api
//https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/    
  $('#output').append('<p><span>Weather in </span> ' + name + ' <img  src=' + match + '>  ' + temp + 'F° / ' + Math.floor(cels) + ' C°</p>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You can refer code from here, I've used Yahoo Weather API over here. https://github.com/SandipNirmal/weather-app-PWA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **resolved** this by using the **code** that is returned from Yahoo API and assigned an image to the specific code:

You can download images from here , allot of options to choose from, in my case i chosen "mono flat": [LINK](https://github.com/mgonzales71/xbmc.artwork)

Also the Yahoo codes and descriptions can be found here: [LINK](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html)

**Then Code:**

> note that you wont see the images but it works on my side.

```js
var queryURL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22anglesey%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

$.getJSON(queryURL, function (data) {
  
  var results = data.query.results
  var firstResult = results.channel.item.condition
  var link = results.channel.image.link
  var img_link_url = results.channel.image.url
  
  var name = results.channel.location.city
  console.log(firstResult);
    console.log(link);
    console.log(img_link_url);
    
  var description = results.channel.item.description
  console.log(description);
    


    var regex = /img.*?src=("|')(.*?)\1/i;
    var match = description.match(regex)[2];
    console.log(match);
    
  var location = firstResult.location // not returned in response
  var temp = firstResult.temp
  var text = firstResult.text
  var code = firstResult.code
  var img
  
  
  
    switch(code) {
    case "0":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/0.png";
        break;            
    case "1":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/1.png";
        break;
    case "2":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/2.png";
        break;
    case "3":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/3.png";
        break;
    case "4":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/4.png";
        break;
    case "5":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/5.png";
        break;
    case "6":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/6.png";
        break;
    case "7":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/7.png";
        break;
    case "8":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/8.png";
        break;
    case "9":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/9.png";
        break;
    case "10":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/10.png";
        break;
    case "11":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/11.png";
        break;
    case "12":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/12.png";
        break;
    case "13":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/13.png";
        break;
    case "14":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/14.png";
        break;
    case "15":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/15.png";
        break;
    case "16":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/16.png";
        break;
    case "17":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/17.png";
        break;
    case "18":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/18.png";
        break;
    case "19":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/19.png";
        break;
    case "20":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/20.png";
        break;
    case "21":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/21.png";
        break;
    case "22":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/22.png";
        break;  
    case "23":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/23.png";
        break;
    case "24":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/24.png";
        break;
    case "25":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/25.png";
        break;
    case "26":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/26.png";
        break;
    case "27":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/27.png";
        break;
    case "28":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/28.png";
        break;
    case "29":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/29.png";
        break;
    case "30":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/30.png";
        break;
    case "31":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/31.png";
        break;
    case "32":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/32.png";
        break; 
    case "33":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/33.png";
        break;
    case "34":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/34.png";
        break;
    case "35":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/35.png";
        break;
    case "36":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/36.png";
        break;  
    case "37":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/37.png";
        break;
    case "38":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/38.png";
        break;
    case "39":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/39.png";
        break;
    case "40":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/40.png";
        break;
    case "41":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/41.png";
        break;
    case "42":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/42.png";
        break;
    case "43":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/43.png";
        break;
    case "44":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/44.png";
        break;
    case "45":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/45.png";
        break;
    case "46":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/46.png";
        break; 
    case "47":
        img = "/images/mono-flat/47.png";
        break;              
    default:
        img = "/images/mono-flat/na.png";
    }
  

  
 var cels =  (temp - 32) * (5 / 9);

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#output').append('<p><span>Weather in </span> ' + name + ' <img width="32px"  src=' + img + '>  ' + temp + 'F° / ' + Math.floor(cels) + ' C°</p>');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure Math.floor() is what you want?

Comment: Hi @AbdulAhad , why not , does exactly what i want.

Comment: Do you want to report 22.9 Celsius as 22 or 23? 57 degrees Fahrenheit as an example.

Comment: well thats a good point , did not even think about the rounding, would want it 23.